# Conditionally load application context

Tags: java, spring, conditional-statements, applicationcontext

How can I load a `spring-beans` xml file from one out of two locations?

- `System.getProperty("conf.dir") + "/context.xml"` if it exist, otherwise fall back to
- `classpath:/context.xml`

This is what I started out with but I *only* want to load the first found context

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"${conf.dir}/context.xml", "classpath:/context.xml"})
public class AppConfig {
     @Autowire somethingFromAboveXmlContext;
}
```

I've looked into `@Conditional` but the solution becomes a bit non-intuitive.

```
@Configuration
@Conditional(AppContextCondition.class)
@ImportResource("${conf.dir}/context.xml")
@ImportResource("classpath:/context.xml")
public class AppConfig {
     @Autowire somethingFromAboveXmlContext;
}
```

Is there a manual approach to do what `ImportResource` does?

Comment: it can be done using @profile annotation as well. 
link : http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2012/06/12/spring-3-1-environment-profiles/

Comment: @anuraggupta can it though? It's not a profile-type of setting but a take-this-if-it-exist type of scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"${conf.dir}/context.xml"})
public class AppConfig {
 static {
    if(!System.getProperties().contains("conf.dir")) {
        System.setProperty("conf.dir", "classpath:");
    }
 }
 @Autowire somethingFromAboveXmlContext;
}
```

I agree that it might not be a perfect solution, but it could work!